# Django: How can i open an App with Django?

Tags: html, django, url

I am currently working on a Django project and have reached a point where I need to implement the final functionalities. However, I am encountering a problem in one specific area. When the app is opened on a smartphone, I want to open the scanner app of that specific smartphone with a button. I have tried using the URL scheme required for my smartphone provider, but that did not work. I have also made sure to allow all relevant permissions in the app settings.

I am stuck and would appreciate any help. Below is the code snippet where the issue occurs:

```html
<span>@{{room.host.username}}</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="room__details">
{{room.description}}
</div>
<span class="room__topics">{{room.topic}}
<a href="xmsf://scan/scanner">Open Scanner App</a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="room__conversation">
<div class="threads scroll">
{% for element in liste %}
<li>{{ element }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you.